# Comparison between Camunda and Alternatives (Activiti)

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn, camunda

I'm doing a comparison between Camunda & other alternatives (eg. Activiti) as a part of a feasibility study.

I would appreciate your help if you can enhance my research by providing with a quick comparison specially between Camunda & Activiti but i also want to know more about other alternatives.

I would prefer a very short comparison listing only important features (distinguishing features like what is possible for one & not for others, licensing, dependencies with other products like tomcat & JBoss & operating systems etc).

Comment: personally I didn't tested activity, but you should get a try to processmaker as part of your research.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As you are familiar with processmaker,can you list out the advantage and disadvantage of processmaker as an open source BPM tool.

Answer (score 4):

For Camunda and Activiti the OpenHub comparison of statistics is quite interesting: https://www.openhub.net/p/_compare?project_0=camunda+BPM+platform&project_1=Activiti

But as I am obviously biased (as Camunda Evangelist) I do not want to go into details myself. You might find these white-papers helpful though: https://network.camunda.org/whitepaper/8, https://network.camunda.org/whitepaper/2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Ok so you don't wanna compare these two here but could you please list out features and advantage of camunda which you think make camunda  as best open source BPM tool.

Comment: We tried our best that you can get an overview yourself quickly: https://camunda.org/ & https://camunda.org/features/ :-)

In short:
# Support of relevant standards: BPMN (workflows), CMMN (Case Management), DMN (Decision Management, also known as Business Rules Management) 
# Very lightweight engine, completely developer friendly, open architecture
# Very powerful in terms of scalability & performance (we have customers doing core processes in a huge scale via the Platform, see also https://camunda.com/customers/)
# Easy to get started (we have various guides online)

Comment: I truly appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

For processmaker as an bpmn you have some advantages like:
**PROSS**

- Flexible triggering points in Task Step
- mobile app support
- great ldap/active directory integrations (just in paid versions, not
  comunity)
- can be modified to doesn't look as processmaker at all if you need something 1005 adapted to your needs:
  http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/Gulliver%3A_Programmer%2527s_Reference_Guide
- Flexible report tools (paid version only)

**cons**

- doesn't has to much real world samples of implementations

using the same comparission above also shows more activity than camunda and activiti  https://www.openhub.net/p/_compare?project_0=camunda+BPM+platform&project_1=Activiti&project_2=ProcessMaker

Comment: I truly appreciate your efforts. It really helps :)